# CakePHP 3 left join and union in same query

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a products table and a metadata table that I want to allow searching of. Having managed to write the query so it works super fast, I'm having trouble migrating it to CakePHP 3.x

The tables are standard parent->child setup with foreign keys and fulltext indexes on the relevant data fields.

The query I want to emulate is:

```
select products.*, sum(hits.relevance) as relevance from (
    SELECT  products.id, MATCH(products.code, products.title) AGAINST('"mm mmm"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as relevance
    FROM    products
    WHERE   MATCH(products.code, products.title) AGAINST('"mm mmm"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
union all
    SELECT  pim1.product_id as id, MATCH(pim1.value) AGAINST('"mm mmm"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as relevance
    FROM    pim1 
    WHERE   MATCH(pim1.value) AGAINST('"mm mmm"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
) as hits
left join products on products.id = hits.id
group by products.id
order by relevance desc
```

Essentially this is allowing MySQL to use the indexes much faster than a left join does, unions the results, then uses that as the primary table to left join the products data to to hand off to paginate() and the view.

I have the unions all sorted, but I can't seem to get the outer query to work.

```
$pim = $this->Products  
       ->association("Pim1")    
       ->find('all')    
       ->select(['fk' => 'product_id']) 
       ->select(['relevance' => 'MATCH(value) AGAINST(:search IN BOOLEAN MODE)'])   
       ->where("MATCH(value) AGAINST(:search IN BOOLEAN MODE)") 
       ->bind(":search", $this->request->session()->read('search.wild_terms'));
$prd = $this->Products
       ->find('all')    
       ->select(['fk' => 'id']) 
       ->select(['relevance' => 'MATCH(code, title) AGAINST(:search IN BOOLEAN MODE)']) 
       ->where("MATCH(code, title) AGAINST(:search IN BOOLEAN MODE)")   
       ->bind(":search", $this->request->session()->read('search.wild_terms'));
```

This bit works and runs the union as per the subquery above

```
$query = $prd->unionAll($pim);
```

This bit doesn't then allow me to attach the products data to the results of that union

```
$query->leftJoinWith("Products", function ($q) { return $q->where(['Products.id' => 'fk']); });
```

It throws an error

> Products is not associated with Products

Any guidance on how to convert my successful SQL into Cake would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`leftJoinWith()` is used for joining associations. Since your Products table is not associated with itself you cannot use it. Instead use `leftJoin()` You will need to pass all the information to that method to build the join conditions.

Comment: That's closer, however as the union doesn't has an alias that I can define/access, so I can't add the join conditions in properly. When I just try and join with Products I get an alias issue with the Product table in the union.